# Storing format information in database for use within a Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am struggling with how to handle formatting data pulled from a database when every customer may/will want their own formatting for some fields.  I have googled around and have found the term data dictionary but no clear explanation of what this is or how I can leverage it in my C# / MSQL Server / Entity Framework windows form application.  I feel like this must be a common problem, and therefore must be a standard or common way of handling this type of requirement.

Example:
I have a field called ReferenceRange (FLOAT) in a table.  Customer X wants this field to be displayed with an accuracy of 2 decimal points and another would like this to be displayed with 1 decimal point of accuracy.

Comment: Store a preference file based on the user where you store the appropriate settings/format strings (file or could be something in the database like a JSON string with setttings). Apply the settings from the preference file when you display the data.

Comment: @RonBeyer how would I apply the JSON settings in the application?

Comment: You would have to apply them in format strings, something like `textBox.Text = someValue.ToString(userPreferences.FieldName);` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a parameter in you app.config file or a config table, them store in that place the customer preference.

On every ToString() read the customer preference decimals to create the corresponding format, like:

ToString("#,##0." + dec), where dec would be your stored value.